# How do I zoom in on X axis when it's a date?

Tags: r

I'm plotting a software version to the date it was released. Example:

**test.cvs**

```
Version,Date
0.302,23/2/2011
0.301,26/1/2011
0.215,28/4/2010
0.106,19/12/2008
0.069,21/3/2008
```

**To plot I use:**

```
tbl <- read.csv("test.csv")
dates <-strptime(as.character(tbl$Date), "%d/%m/%Y")
plot(dates,tbl$Version,type="o",main="Releases", xlab="Date",ylab="Version")
```

It plots it by year though, I rather want it to plot by month/year, and have the labels printed vertically. How could I accomplish this? I tried setting xaxt="n" and using the axis() function with label=format(data,fmt) but I keep failing.

**dput of data snippet:**

```
structure(list(Version = c(0.302, 0.301, 0.215, 0.106, 0.069), 
    Date = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("19/12/2008", 
    "21/3/2008", "23/2/2011", "26/1/2011", "28/4/2010"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Version", 
"Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a base graphics version. First, it is easier to manipulate the `Date` column in-place rather than produce an extra `dates` object:

```
tbl <- within(tbl, Date <- as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

This then does the plot. Note we need a bit more margin space on the bottom to accommodate the date labels:

```
op <- par(mar = c(6,4,4,2) + 0.1) ## larger bottom margin
## plot data but suppress axes and annotation
plot(Version ~ Date, data = tbl, type = "o", axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE)
## Use Axis to plot the Date axis, in 1 month increments
## format the sequence of dates `ds` as abbreviated month name and Year
with(tbl, Axis(Date, at = (ds <- seq(min(Date), max(Date), by = "months")),
               side = 1, labels = format(ds, format = "%b %Y"), las = 2))
## Add y-axis and plot frame
axis(2)
box()
## add on the axis labels
title(ylab = "Version", main = "Releases")
title(xlab = "Date", line = 5) ## pushing the x-axis label down a bit
par(op) ## reset the pars
```

This gives us:

[image: plot with custom Date axis]

More flexibility can be gained by altering the sequence of dates we want, here we want every 2 months, and we label them with 2-digit century:

```
with(tbl, Axis(Date, at = (ds <- seq(min(Date), max(Date), by = "2 months")),
               side = 1, labels = format(ds, format = "%b %y"), las = 2))
```

To use this just swap in the above call in place of the existing `with(....)` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Create a sequence of dates for your axis labels.

```
start <- as.Date("01/01/2008", "%d/%m/%Y")
end <- as.Date("01/12/2011", "%d/%m/%Y")
x_breaks <- seq(start, end, by = "month")
```

Create `dates` as a `Date` to match the above sequence.

```
dates <- as.Date(as.character(tbl$Date), "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Set some graphical params, `las = 3` rotates your x axis; `mar` changes margin widths.

```
par(las = 3, mar = c(7, 5, 3, 1))
```

Now draw it, and manually add the x axis, as you suggested.

```
plot(dates,tbl$Version,type="o",main="Releases", xlab="", ylab="Version", xaxt = "n")
axis(side = 1, at = as.numeric(x_breaks), labels = strftime(x_breaks, "%b %Y"))
title(xlab = "Date", line = 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using `ggplot2`. Here is some code

```
# generate data frame
df = data.frame(
       Version = rnorm(20),
       Date    = seq(as.Date('2010-01-01'), by = '1 month', length = 20)
     )

# create plot
p0 = qplot(Date, Version, data = df) +
     scale_x_date(major = '1 month') +
     opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle = 90))
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: I do like this answer because it gives the grid and is short, but I chose the other because it had a lot of useful information I did not know. Thank you though